# Magento2 - WYSIWYG uploader missing folders

Tags: magento2, wysiwyg

I would like to know why folders are not appearing in the WYSIWYG image uploader.

In `image1` below, only "test" folder appears (`pub/media/test`), but I have another folder "`test+`" that is not appearing (see `image2`)

[image: Image 1]
[image: Image 2]

Answer (score 0):

In Magento 2 Folder name is not support the another sign like +, -, etc.. 
Magento 2 support the only alphabetical folder name, 
Please check screen-short, https://prnt.sc/r0hw22

Thanks.

Comment: Hello @V Salvador your working the solutions so accept the answer

Comment: so i can helpful another community